# Mailchimp API - Return certain fields only in JSON response

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic, mailchimp

I need to create a newsletter archive on our website so our users have access to previously sent campaigns we have sent via Mailchimp.

I'm trying to return a list of the archive_url and send_time fields from the Campaigns method. The kicker is I need to use Classic ASP to return the data.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server" src="/global/json2.min.asp"></script>

Dim oXMLHTTP
Set oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
varUrl = "https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns?offset=0&count=20"

oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", varUrl, False
oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type","application/json"
oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "apikey xxx"
oXMLHTTP.send

responseText = oXMLHTTP.responseText

set myJson = JSON.parse(responseText)
archiveURL = myJson.archive_url
sendTime = myJson.send_time

response.write(archiveURL)
response.write(sendTime )
```

I can return the full response without issue, but can't select the fields I only need. When I try the code above, IIS returns the following error:

*Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6*

*Object doesn't support this property or method: 'myJson.archive_url'*

*/global/requests.asp, line 25*

Any help with what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Cheers